# Get a file size from the URL

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

I have a list of URLs to images/videos. I want to show the file size along with the image on the website. I use regular img tag to render the image. Now, I need to show the size of the file as an additional detail.

I am using Angular and I tried the following:

```
this._httpGet(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
```

But it did not help. It gives unwanted results.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: the http HEAD method is probably what you want - assuming you're not dealing with cross origin requests without CORS

Comment: you can create file object and then use `file.size` `const blob = this._httpGet(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
const file = new File([blob], "filename",  {type: blob.type});
console.log(file.size)`

Comment: any example @JaromandaX ? Thank you.

Comment: @Usama Blob is always '{size: 3393type: "text/html"}'.

Comment: `fetch(url,{method:"head"}).then(({headers})=>headers.get("content-length"))`

Answer (score 0):

Service to Fetch the Blob and Calculate Size: Create a service in Angular that uses HttpClient to fetch the resource as a Blob. Then, calculate the file size from this Blob.

Displaying Image and Size in Component: Use the service in your component to fetch the size and display it alongside the image.

Here's a simple implementation:

Step 1: Service Creation

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileSizeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchFileSize(url: string): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
      map(blob => blob.size)
    );
  }
}
```

This service has a method fetchFileSize that makes an HTTP GET request to the provided URL and returns an Observable of the file size.

Step 2: Component Implementation
In your component, you can use this service to fetch the size for each URL and store it in a variable to be displayed in your template.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileSizeService } from './file-size.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-display',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of imageUrlList">
      <img [src]="item.url" alt="image">
      <p>Size: {{item.size}} bytes</p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ImageDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  imageUrlList: Array<{ url: string, size?: number }> = [
    { url: 'https://example.com/image1.jpg' },
    // ... other URLs
  ];

  constructor(private fileSizeService: FileSizeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.imageUrlList.forEach(item => {
      this.fileSizeService.fetchFileSize(item.url).subscribe(size => {
        item.size = size;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In this component, you have a list of image URLs. For each URL, the component calls fetchFileSize and updates the size in the imageUrlList.

Comment: Please note that [ChatGPT answers are banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. Unfortunately, this is almost the same as mine. It wont give a proper results. always results in 3393.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can use the following method to determine the file size of an image or video from a URL. The trick is to send a HEAD request to the server to obtain only the headers, including the "Content-Length" header, which indicates the size of the file.

```js
  getFileSize(url: string): Promise<number> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.http.head(url, { headers, observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        const contentLength = response.headers.get('Content-Length');
        if (contentLength) {
          return parseInt(contentLength, 10);
        } else {
          throw new Error('Content-Length header not found');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching file size:', error);
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

You can utilize this service in your component as follows:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileSizeService.getFileSize(this.imageUrl)
      .then(size => {
        console.log(size, '==>file size');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I get the error 'Error fetching file size: Error: Content-Length header not found'